# XML Encoding errors

Tags: php, xml

Because of those lines, I am getting  Encoding error, Mainly the problem is with accent 
I am using this to create my xml

```
$xml_document = new DOMDocument( '1.0','utf-8' );
$xml_document->formatOutput = true;
```

```
$description = $xml_document->createElement("description"); 
$description->appendChild($xml_document->createCDATASection( ( strip_tags( str_replace( "</p>", "\n\n", $result['post_content'] ) ) ) ) );
$job_element->appendChild($description);
```

And this to print it: 

`echo $xml_document->saveXML();
echo $xml_document->save('/var/www/html/maifeed.xml');`
 
I have others elements with root, when i //comment this description section all is working fine. 
the description can contain tags and accents, And looks like mainly i have problems with accents this is an exemple of a data causing a problem.

Profil

```
 <description><![CDATA[Sous la responsabilité de la Responsable Communication, Image et Culture, vous définissez la stratégie et vous assurez de son déploiement à l'international sur l'ensemble des sujets Image et contenus de marque

Profil

Minimum 5 d'expérience au service communication d'une marque luxe / premium ou en agence de communication sur des comptes luxe / premium.
Sensibilité et curiosité créative indispensable
Très bonne connaissance des métiers et talents créatifs et artistiques (dont photographes, directeurs artistiques, partenaires de production...)
Excellent niveau de français impératif (lu, parlé et écrit) et anglais professionnel (lu, parlé et écrit)
Autonomie et forte capacité à être moteur et force de proposition
Rigueur opérationnelle, sens du détail]]></description>
```

In mozilla i am getting this

```
 <description><![CDATA[Sous la responsabilit
```

If i delete the descriptions which are causing problems, all is working fine. But it's not a solution. 
This is the error showing in chrome:

This page contains the following errors:
error on line 19401 at column 27: Encoding error
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Comment: Is `$result['post_content']` encoded as UTF-8? What exact bytes are you obtaining as seen in e.g. an [hexadecimal editor](https://hexed.it))?

Comment: i used     echo mb_detect_encoding($result['post_content']);
i am getting asci as result

Comment: `mb_detect_encoding()` is pretty much useless. But [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII-printable-characters) doesn't even have a code for `é`. What exact bytes are you obtaining as seen in e.g. an [hexadecimal editor](https://hexed.it/)?